# "as good compared to something": what is the meaning of the "good"?

Tags: word-meaning

Simple question: what is the meaning of the "good" in the phrase "as good compared to something"?

I sometimes see this expression but don't sure what the "good" means and whether it is necessary or natural usage...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Good" literally means "good" in this construction, which can be seen as "[noun] is as [adjective] as [noun]". The two nouns are being compared, and they have equal values of whatever the adjective is.

For example, "a bus is as noisy as an airplane", "a cheetah is as fast as a jaguar", "an ice cream is as expensive as a chocolate bar", etc.

One can also say "a turkey breast is not as tasty as a chicken breast".

Comment: I know the grammar of "A is as [adjective] as B" however the phrase of my question looks different from the construction, doesn't it?

Comment: Your question doesn't quote a complete construction. The word "compared" isn't necessary, as "as" performs the comparison. "Chicken is as good compared to turkey" sounds slightly clunky to me, whereas "chicken is as good as turkey" is more natural.

Comment: The sentence came from the first post of the forum http://www.cloudynights.com/topic/376228-lodestar-vs-superstar/. I feel "as good" is needless in the sentence.

Comment: @TaikiBessho: it would have been better to quote the entire sentence, which would be easier to read if there were a comma after the word "good" and before "compared". People who write on forum messageboards don't always use grammatical English.